# Pandas get average time interval within groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame containing an `EffectiveDate` column.
I want to groupby the DataFrame by a Key value and then calculate the average time interval for all the date values in each group for the `EffectiveDate` column.

For example for the DataFrame:

```
    EffectiveDate
1   2015-08-17 07:00:00
1   2015-08-18 07:00:00
1   2015-08-19 07:00:00
2   2015-08-20 07:00:00
2   2015-08-21 07:00:00
2   2015-09-16 07:00:00
2   2015-10-15 07:00:00
2   2015-11-16 08:00:00
```

I want to groupby the Index and calculate the average interval between the date values in the EffectiveDate column.

```
15199   2015-08-17 07:00:00
15214   2015-08-18 07:00:00
15219   2015-08-19 07:00:00
15233   2015-08-20 07:00:00
15254   2015-08-21 07:00:00
15687   2015-09-16 07:00:00
199     2015-10-15 07:00:00
1123    2015-11-16 08:00:00
Name: EffectiveDate, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

On a single Series this seems to work fine:

```
EffectiveDate.diff().astype('timedelta64[s]').mean()
```

However when I am using the same function as a groupby aggregate on a pandas DataFrame:

```
df.groupby('Key').agg({
    'EffectiveDate': lambda x: x.diff().astype('timedelta64[s]').mean()
})
```

The results are

```
                  EffectiveDate                               
1 1970-01-01 00:00:00.016747425
2 1970-01-01 00:00:00.017765280
3 1970-01-01 00:00:00.034776096
4 1970-01-01 00:00:00.002052450
5 1970-01-01 00:00:00.018238800
6 1970-01-01 00:00:00.024005438 
7 1970-01-01 00:00:00.012330000
```

I would expect an integer field in each column. I am using Pandas `0.19.2`.

Comment: The results will be a mean for each group in the `Key` column, which doesn't seem to correspond to your output. Can you please include your full DataFrame and exactly what you are doing?

Comment: Also, what version of Pandas are you using? I cannot reproduce this with 0.18.1.

Comment: @Mitch you are right. I am not able to reproduce this in 0.18.1, I'm using 0.19.2

Comment: _Very_ strange, huh. I'll try and test it tomorrow for you if no one has come around by then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) seems to attempt to cast *back* to the original dtype of the EffectiveDate column in `0.19.2`. This might make sense generally I think, as we would expect an aggregation down the column to have the same dtype.

To fix this issue, you could use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) instead in `0.19.2`, which doesn't perform the same cast afterwards.

```
df.groupby(df.index).apply(
    lambda x: x.diff().astype('timedelta64[s]').mean()
)
```

Seemingly this didn't used to be the case, as I can reproduce your behavior in `0.18.1` only after casting *to* the original dtype of the EffectiveDate column.

**In `0.18.1`**

```
>>> df
        EffectiveDate
1 2015-08-17 07:00:00
1 2015-08-18 07:00:00
1 2015-08-19 07:00:00
2 2015-08-20 07:00:00
2 2015-08-21 07:00:00
2 2015-09-16 07:00:00
2 2015-10-15 07:00:00
2 2015-11-16 08:00:00

>>> df.groupby(df.index).agg({
        'EffectiveDate': lambda x: x.diff().astype('timedelta64[s]').mean()
})

   EffectiveDate
1        86400.0
2      1901700.0

>>> df.groupby(df.index).agg({
        'EffectiveDate': lambda x: x.diff().astype('timedelta64[s]').mean()
}).astype(df.EffectiveDate.dtype)

                  EffectiveDate
1 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000086400
2 1970-01-01 00:00:00.001901700
```